# Imagine a universe with only 2 objects:

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, observers

a single electron and a detector for magnetic fields. If the electron is moving at a constant velocity, will the detector ever register a magnetic field?

Comment: Related: [Does a single moving charge produce magnetic field in an empty universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/807959/does-a-single-moving-charge-produce-magnetic-field-in-an-empty-universe)

Comment: Interesting… two accounts ask the same question on the same day.

Comment: Can I get a proper answer? quiet new to this site professor said I could ask for help here.

Comment: @AdonayGandolffi Please slow down and take your time when writing questions. The questions will likely be downvoted and closed if you do not ask the question clearly. Please also use the search bar at the top of the website to first search for similar question. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AdonayGandolffi The same goes for answering. You don't need to necropost a new answer to a question that has already been answered unless your new answer is somehow reasonably better than the old answer... especially if the answer has previously been accepted. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: A moving charge produces a magnetic field. Why won’t your professor answer your questions?

Comment: @hft Al right thanks so much for the recomendation. I really appreciate it

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liénard–Wiechert_potential)

Comment: If you have been posed this question as an exercise then I suggest you will learn more by thinking about it from what knowledge you have and then possibly making a mistake (and learning that it was a mistake) than by asking other people to tell you the answer.

Comment: @AndrewSteane  thanks so much for the suggestion sir Andrew. I really appreciate it

Comment: I assume the electron is moving with constant velocity *relative to* the magnetic field detector?

Answer (score 4):

> If the electron is moving at a constant velocity, will the detector ever register a magnetic field?

If a point charge (e.g., an electron) is moving at a constant velocity, the electromagnetic field can be determined by boosting [the field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) of a static point charge.

---

In the *rest* frame of the charge, the electric field of a point charge of charge q is:
$$
\vec E_{rest}=\frac{q \vec r}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^3} \;.
$$
and the magnetic field is:
$$
\vec B_{rest}= 0 \;.
$$

And the [field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor) is thus:
$$
F^{\mu\nu}_{rest}=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & -\frac{q x}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3} & -\frac{q y}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3} & -\frac{q z}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3}
\\
\frac{q x}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
\frac{q y}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
\frac{q z}{4\pi c \epsilon_0 r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

In the boosted frame, where the electron is moving with a fixed velocity $\vec v$, [the field strength tensor is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Transformation_of_the_electromagnetic_field):
$$
F^{\mu\nu}(\vec v) = \Lambda(\vec v)^{\mu}_{\mu'}\Lambda(\vec v)^{\nu}_{\nu'} F^{\mu'\nu'}_{rest}\;,
$$
where $\Lambda(\vec v)$ is [the usual boost Lorentz transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Physical_formulation_of_Lorentz_boosts) for a boost of speed $v$ in the $\hat v$ direction.

If you find that any of the purely spatial ($i,j$) components of $F^{\mu\nu}(\vec v)$ are non-zero then you will have found that there is a magnetic field for the electron moving at velocity $\vec v$.

Comment: If the detector is in the same inertial frame of reference as the charge (i.e moving at the same velocity), with no acceleration, it will not register a magnetic field, otherwise it will. This is one of the issues that led Einstein to write his 1905 paper on SR. A similar question is answered here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge